# How to STOP Combobox from updating source data when the selection changes?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, binding

I have a `ComboBox` displaying people, a `TextBox` for firstname, a `TextBox` for lastname, a `Button` to save the entered data. The user may enter what ever he wants in the `TextBox`es and when he clicks the 'save' button the contents of the `TextBox`es should be saved to the currently selected person.

This is how my `TextBox`es look like in XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Combobox x:Name="cbPerson" ItemsSource={Binding Source={StaticResource collection_people}
          SelectedValue={Binding Path=Firstname} DisplayMemberPath={Binding Path=Firstname}
          SelectedValuePath={Binding Path=Firstname}/>

    <Textbox x:Name="tbFirstname" Text="{Binding Path=name, Mode=TwoWay,
          UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}}" Width="Auto"/>

    <Textbox x:Name="tbLastname" Text="{Binding Path=name, Mode=TwoWay, 
          UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}}" Width="Auto">
</Grid>
```

This is how my `Button` function looks like:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tbFirstname.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
    tbLastname.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
}
```

In my Person class I implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in order for the TwoWay binding to work.

When I select an item from the `ComboBox` the `TextBox`es get filled with the according data. I can then edit the `TextBox`es and save the data to the object by pressing the save button. Everything works as you would expect except for one thing:

For instance, when I select "Paul" from the `ComboBox` and change the text of the  firstname `TextBox` from **"Paul" to "Leo"** and then select another item from the `ComboBox` WITHOUT clicking the save button, the object previous object ("Paul") gets updated nevertheless.

Why is that and how can I fix this? I haven't had any success finding something related to this problem.

Comment: Is `Text={Binding="{Binding ...` a typo? Do you just mean `Text="{Binding ...`?

Comment: Yes, a typo. Updated it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this for your **XAML** code?

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cbPerson" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource collection_people}}"
              DisplayMemberPath="FirstName"/>

    <TextBox x:Name="tbFirstName" 
             Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.FirstName, ElementName=cbPerson, Mode=TwoWay,
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" 
             Width="Auto"/>

    <TextBox x:Name="tbLastName" 
             Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.LastName, ElementName=cbPerson, Mode=TwoWay, 
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" 
             Width="Auto"/>
</Grid>
```

Your `click` event handler be like,

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tbFirstName.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
    tbLastName.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
}
```